# Using SQL views in Play Framework 2.1.x with Ebean

Tags: sql, postgresql, playframework, ebean

I have an application which is using Play Framework 2.1.x with Ebean. I would like to use SQL views (PostgreSQL v9.3) instead of actual tables. I tried to switch the "name" property in @Table annotation from actual table name to view name. Retrieving data from view to Ebean model works nice, but when there is a ManyToMany association, it generates an error. The problem is in name convention used by Ebean in order to generate JOIN clauses in SQL query.

For example I have a table named "customers" and a view named "customers_view" and ManyToMany association with table "customertags". In such case, Ebean generates JOIN clause using bridge table "customers_customerstags". But when I change @Table`s name property to "customers_view", associations are messed up. Ebean then generates JOIN with table "customers_view_customerstags" and so on.

I know that this can be fixed by using @JoinTable and @JoinColumn, BUT at first I want to ask some more experienced programmers if there is some other proper way on how to use SQL views in Play/Ebean which I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing anything. In the absence of @JoinTable etc Ebean is using a naming convention based on the table name (which is now your view).

An alternative work around to this issue by creating a view for the intersection table.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That is what I was afraid of. Another solution would be to rename the actual table to someting else like "customers_data" and then create view named "customers". Then the naming convention should match.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a partial solution for this. There is a function in Ebean`s ServerConfig class called setNamingConvention. With this function you can set your own implementation of interface NamingConvention or you can override functions in included classes from Ebean.

I tried to override Ebean`s default implementation called UnderscoreNamingConvention. By overriding of function getM2MJoinTableName I was able to fix errors regarding creation of join table name in SQL query. Unfortunately join columns are still wrong. Join columns are generated from function NamingConvention.getTableName. It is also possible to override this function, but such change would break generation of FROM part of SQL.

Too bad there is no way to override generation of join columns in NamingConvention interface.

It seems there is no escape from this. Reasonable workaround is to use @JoinTable.